# Django - Log User Activity (Query - GET/FILTER/UPDATE/DELETE) To Database

Tags: django, database, logging, model, signals

I'm building a HIPAA compliant application and I would like to log every user action to the database.

That includes when a user calls a `get`, `filter`, or `delete` object method on a model. I would like to add this functionality to a pre-existing application.

```
_ = ModelA.objects.get(id=1)
_ = ModelA.objects.filter(age__gt=10)
_ = ModelA.objects.filter(age__lt=5).delete()
```

I want to log every database operation.
`Django Activity Stream` does not work for `get` method.

How do I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [django-hipaa](https://github.com/PSU-OIT-ARC/django-hipaa), it can give you a framework from which to work.  I didn't copy it directly, but the idea is to create an abstract logging model--very simplistically:

```
#in models.py
    
class Log(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=PROTECT) #because you want to preserve the log
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    action_taken = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then for each database that you want to log, create a log model:

```
#still in models.py

class ModelALog(Log):
    row = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=Protect)
    #whatever other information you want to log
```

then when in your views.py, you save a log anytime you create a view that involves a database query that you want to log:

```
#in views.py

def some_view_with_ModelA(request):
    something = ModelA.objects.get(pk=1)
    log = ModelALog.objects.create(user=request.user, 
          action_take='your description', row=something)
    return render(yourview.html)
```

This may potentially mean that you have to create additional views to perform the same functions as might otherwise be done from the admin portal, but it ensures all events you want logged are logged.

You might also look into the package [django-safedelete](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-safedelete) as you contemplate deleting, and this package provides a soft-delete so the deleted information is still preserved to protect the integrity of your logs.